# trying to render a partial from click on rails 4, getting 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, partial

I've looked up how to render a partial in Rails 4 and I'm having some problems. I want a form to render when I click a link, but after following some directions I am getting a 500 internal server error.

here is my link code with a remote: true

```
<%= link_to "Lostings", new_losting_path, remote: true, id: "lostings_span" %>
```

here is my controller with the appropriate route/path

```
def new # dont need this later
  @losting = Losting.new
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json
  end
end
```

and here is my new.js.erb file

```
     $("#asset_nav").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render "new") %>');
```

and lastly here is the form partial i am trying to show

```
 <div class="container"> 
 <h3>Lost</h3>
 <%= form_for @losting, remote: true, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :pet_name, "Pet name:" %>
 <%= f.text_field :pet_name %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

when I click the link I get this error.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/lostings/new 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What is wrong and what do i need to do in order to correctly render the partial?

Comment: What's the server log say?  Is your 'new' template a partial?  The file should be named `_new` (beginning w/ an underscore).

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

From what I can see, the main problem you have is you're handling the `ajax` call incorrectly

The way you'd be best doing it is to render the pure HTML, and then capture it in your JS:

```
#app/controllers/lostings_controller.rb
Class LostingsController < ApplicationController

   layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.xhr? false : "application" }

   def new
      @losting = Losting.new #-> will load the /views/new.html.erb template
   end
end
```

This will enable you to append the pure HTML with your JS (with the [Rails ajax UJS callbacks](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#lostings_span").on("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr){
   $("#asset_nav").prepend(data);
});
```

This will give you the ability to append the returned data from your ajax request. The problem is if you wanted to append the direct html on your frontend